# Changing the order of integration of double integral: references and theorems

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, integration

The Fubini's theorem states that if we have $ \int_0^{\infty}  \int_0^{\infty} |f(t,x)| dt dx$ well defined (i.e. function is absolutely integrable) then we can interchange order of integration:

$$ \int_0^{\infty}  \int_0^{\infty} f(t,x) dt dx =  \int_0^{\infty}  \int_0^{\infty} f(t,x) dx dt$$

but there are other cases for which we can change the order of integration without having this condition fullfield.

So my question is :
what are the theorem covering these cases ? Any reference/book where we can find the different cases for which we can interchange the order of integration without the absolute convergence of double integral ?

One simple example where we can interchange integrals without absolute convergence: Consider for example (with for example $f(t)$ of rapid decrease at inifinity and $\sim t^2$ near zero):

$$ \int_0^{\infty}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y) dy dx $$

the integral is not absolutely convergent, but if we split the integral in two parts (on the $x$ variable), we have for the first one:

$$ \int_0^{A}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y) dy dx =    \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{A} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y) dx dy $$

as $ \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{A} | \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y)| dx dy $ is well defined.

For the second part an integration by parts gives:

$$ \int_A^{\infty}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y) dy dx = [  \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{-\cos(xy)}{xy}f(y) dy]_A^{\infty} -  \int_A^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(xy)}{x^2}f(y) dy dx $$

On the other hand we have also by integration by part:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \int_A^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y) dx dy = \int_0^{\infty} [    \frac{-\cos(xy)}{xy}f(y) ]_A^{\infty} dy -  \int_0^{\infty}  \int_A^{\infty} \frac{\cos(xy)}{x^2}f(y) dx dy $$

And as the double integral on the right is absolutely convergent we have:

$$\int_0^{\infty}  \int_A^{\infty} \frac{\cos(xy)}{x^2}f(y) dx dy = \int_A^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{\cos(xy)}{x^2}f(y) dy dx  $$

Meaning that

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \int_A^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y) dx dy=  \int_A^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y) dy dx$$

so finally putting these results together we conclude:

$$ \int_0^{\infty}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y) dy dx =\int_0^{\infty}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x}f(y) dx dy  $$

Comment: I might guess that there is some condition involving uniform integrability.

Comment: You certainly know that for positive measurable functions Fubini's theorem holds. Instead of $\int \int |f(x,y)|dxdy<\infty$ it is enough to assume that one of the integrals of the positive or negative part of $f$ is finite.

Comment: Do you make reference to Theorem 1 mentionned here ?
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)

Comment: @JochenWengenroth, but (outside of the absolutely integrable case) [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295790/changing-the-order-of-integration-of-double-integral-references-and-theorems#comment735422_295790)'s only useful for showing that certain iterated integrals diverge, not for computing convergent iterated integrals, right?